# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect() causing database not to connect to php server

Tags: php, database, postgresql

I'm using php to validate forms and connect to my database but I get `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function pg_connect()` even though I've uncommented these extension in my php.ini file

```
extension=pdo_pgsql
extension=pgsql
```

and restarted my Apache server several times. I still get the same error. I've tried everything and am now at loss. can yawl please help.

```
<?php

$conn= pg_connect("$host=####### $port=#### $dbname=######## $user=####### $password=######3");
if ($conn == True);
   echo 'connection sucessful'
else 
   die (echo 'connection succesful');

?>
```

Comment: Did you edit the correct `php.ini`? Does `phpinfo()` say the extension is enabled?

Comment: Well, looks as if the postgreqsql drive is still not enabled ... Or not even installed. What does your http server's error log file contain?

Comment: @brombeer it doesn't show it. how do I go about enabling it?

Comment: Enable it in the `php.ini` mentioned in `phpinfo()`